# Specific language Yup validation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, formik, yup

I've been using Yup and Formik for form validation in React. How can I set validation for input language? I want to a user can (and only can) write in a specific language (change the default language of the keyboard)

```
const validationSchema = yup.object().shape({
  first_name: yup.string().required("Required *"),
  last_name: yup.string().required("Required *"),
 });
```

Comment: Please be more clear on what you mean by "set validation for input language", do you have an input named `language` and want to add validation to that field? You want to validate if the input text is from certain language? It's kind of confusing what want to do

Comment: I want to validate if the input text is from certain language

Comment: @Vencovsky I want to a user can write in a specific language (change the default language of the keyboard)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Regex pattern. For example for the English language:

```
const nameRegex = /^[A-Za-z]+$/;

const validationSchema = yup.object().shape({
  first_name: yup.string().matches(nameRegex, "Only English letters").required("Required *"),
  last_name: yup.string().matches(nameRegex, "Only English letters").required("Required *"),
 });
```